# How to put a List<class> into a JSONObject and then read that object?

Tags: java, json, class, list

I have a `List<class>` that I would like to convert into a json object and then traverse the data out of the json object.

If this were just a `List<String>` I could just do something like:

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
List<String> sList = new ArrayList<String>();
sList.add("val1");
sList.add("val2");

obj.put("list", sList);
```

Then I could traverse the list like:

```
JSONArray jArray = obj.getJSONArray("list");
for (int ii = 0; ii < jArray.size(); ii++)
    System.out.println(jArray.getString(ii));
```

The problem with using the class is that I need to have access to data within each class element of my `List<class>` and I don't know how to encode that / traverse it into JSON. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which `JSONObject` class are you using? There are a few...

Comment: Good point, I had assumed it was the org.json classes.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Call `getJSONObject()` instead of `getString()`. That will give you a handle on the JSON object in the array and then you can get the property off of the object from there.

For example, to get the property "value" from a `List<SomeClass>` where `SomeClass` has a `String getValue()` and `setValue(String value)`:

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
List<SomeClass> sList = new ArrayList<SomeClass>();

SomeClass obj1 = new SomeClass();
obj1.setValue("val1");
sList.add(obj1);

SomeClass obj2 = new SomeClass();
obj2.setValue("val2");
sList.add(obj2);

obj.put("list", sList);

JSONArray jArray = obj.getJSONArray("list");
for(int ii=0; ii < jArray.length(); ii++)
  System.out.println(jArray.getJSONObject(ii).getString("value"));
```

Comment: don't work for me. I can't parse array from jsonObject. JSONArray jArray = obj.getJSONArray("list"); will give me a exception.

  JSONArray list = new JSONArray(iconIds);
  obj.put("list", list);

This works.  I can parse array from obj
JSONArray jArray = obj.getJSONArray("list");

Answer (score 3):

Let us assume that the class is **Data** with two objects **name** and **dob** which are both **strings**.

> Initially, check if the list is empty. Then, add the objects from the list to a **JSONArray**

```
JSONArray allDataArray = new JSONArray();
List<Data> sList = new ArrayList<Data>();

//if List not empty
if (!sList.isEmpty()) {

    //Loop index size()
    for(int index = 0; index < sList.size(); index++) {
        JSONObject eachData = new JSONObject();
        try {
            eachData.put("name", sList.get(index).getName());
            eachData.put("dob", sList.get(index).getDob());
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        allDataArray.put(eachData);
    }
} else {
    //Do something when sList is empty
}
```

> Finally, add the **JSONArray** to a **JSONObject**.

```
JSONObject root = new JSONObject();
try {
    root.put("data", allDataArray);
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

> You can further get this data as a **String** too.

```
String jsonString = root.toString();
```

Answer (score 2):

This is how I do it using Google Gson. I am not sure, if there are a simpler way to do this (with or without an external library).

```
Type collectionType = new TypeToken<List<Class>>() {
}.getType();

String gsonString = new Gson().toJson(objList, collectionType);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a JSON serializer/deserializer like [flexjson](http://flexjson.sourceforge.net/) to do the conversion for you.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but I would like to avoid using a serializer at all costs if I can.

Comment: Okay, since you want to stick with JSONArray and JSONObject, I provided an alternate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just to update this thread, here is how to add a list (as a json array) into JSONObject.
Plz substitute YourClass with your class name;

```
List<YourClass> list = new ArrayList<>();
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();

org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper objectMapper = new 
org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper();
org.codehaus.jackson.JsonNode listNode = objectMapper.valueToTree(list);
org.json.JSONArray request = new org.json.JSONArray(listNode.toString());
jsonObject.put("list", request);
```